# Google Analytics API data mismatch

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

I set up a custom variables to get `data` from `Google Analytics` and store into a local database.

**Requirement :** 
 I want to get a list of the `users`,`sessions`,`event label`,`total events`,`unique events`,`event value`,`operating system`,`browser` and `device category`.

**Problem :**

I've checked the dashboard on Google Analytics, and the data is being reported fine. However, I noticed that on the Google Analytics, the data listed in the column **`unique events`** don't match the amounts I get when requesting the **`Google Analytics API`**.

**Data shows by GA :**

[image]

**Data shows by GA API :**

[image]

**Query that i am using in GA API :**

```
public function getEventsLabelByDate($params=array()) {

        $defaults = array(
            'metrics' => 'ga:visitors,ga:visits,ga:totalEvents,ga:uniqueEvents,ga:eventValue',
            'dimensions' => 'ga:eventLabel,ga:eventCategory,ga:country,ga:operatingSystem,ga:browser,ga:date,ga:deviceCategory',
            'filters' => 'ga:eventAction==Play Done',
        );
        $_params = array_merge($defaults, $params);
        return $this->_query($_params);

    }   

$data = $ga->getEventsLabelByDate();
```

I want to know what's best to use in my `API calls`. 
 Any immediate help will be highly appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: You should wait until tomorrow and try again. Reporting for same-day traffic isn't guaranteed to be up-to-the-minute accurate.

Comment: @Philip..I totally agree with you but I here I request yesterday data please see the date range I selected..

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue.

My workaround was to change the dimensions to ga:eventCategory and then summed up the returned uniqueEvents. That provided a number identical to the uniqueEvent per eventAction on the web interface.

Using more granular dimensions resulted in an accurate number. Hope that works for you too.